# Помогите найти в двумерном массиве два одинаковых элемента и их индексы с++

Tags: c++

Матрица содержит два одинаковых элемента. Найдите эти элементы и их индексы (никакой элемент матрицы не должен сравниваться сам с собой).
не работает

```
        #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int m, n;
cout << "enter row ";
cin >> m;
cout << "enter cols ";
cin >> n;

int **A = new int*[m];
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    A[i] = new int [n];
}
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
           cout << "vvedite element" << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << k << "]" << " = " ;
           cin >> A[i][k];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for(int  i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      {
          cout << A[i][k] <<' ';
      }
cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        for (int s = i; s < m; s++)
            for (int t = k + 1; t < n; t++)
                if (A[i][k] == A[s][t])
                    cout << "A[" << i << "][ " << k << "] == A[ " << s << "][" << t << "]" << endl;



for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    delete [] A[i];
}
delete [] A;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const int n = 4;
const int m = 5;
int mass[n][m];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        mass[i][j] = rand() % 90;
        std::cout << mass[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int s = i; s < n; s++)
        {
            for (int t = j + 1; t < m; t++)
                if (mass[i][j] == mass[s][t])
                {
                    std::cout << "mass[" << i << "][ " << j <<
                        "] == mass[ " << s << "][" << t << "]" << std::endl;
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: у меня не работает,можете пожалуйста объяснить для чего последние два цикла ?

Comment: Последние два цикла находят значения от `mass[i][j+1]` до конца массива

Comment: А что именно у вас не работает ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int c, r, i, j, m[100][100], el, c_el, r_el, i_el, j_el; //Объявление переменных
 cout<<"Размер двумерного массива"<<endl; 
 cout<<"Введите количество столбцов-->";
 cin>>c;
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"Введите количество строк-->";
 cin>>r;
 cout<<endl;
 For (i=0; i<c; i++) //Заполнение массива
 { 
   For (j=0; j<r; i++)
   {
    cout<<"Введите элемент M["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] -->";
    cin<<M[i][j];
   }
 }

 cout<<"Заполненная матрица:"<<endl;
 For (i=0; i<c; i++)
 { 
   For (j=0; j<r; i++)
   {
    cout<<"M[i][j]";
   }
  cout<<endl;
 }
 c_el = c;
 r_el = r;
For (i_el=0; i_el<c_el; i_el++)
{
 el = M[i_el][j_el];
 For (j_el=0; j_el<0; j_el++)
 {
 For (i=0; i<c; i++) 
 { 
   For (j=0;j<r;i++)
   {
    if (el==M[i][j] && c_el<>i && r_el<>j) //Сравниваем значения, если разные индексы
     {
     cout<<"Элемент M["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] и Элемент M["<<c_el<<"]["<<r_el<<"] имеют одинаковое значение ="<< M[i][j]<<endl;
     break;
     } 
    }
   }
  }
 }
```